# Javascript map method

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

Does the map method always use a `return` statement?

Because in this example, there is a return statement showing in the myFunction function:

```
const numbers1 = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];
const numbers2 = numbers1.map(myFunction);

function myFunction(value, index, array) {
  return value * 2;
}
```

Comment: What would you expect it to look like and do _without_ a return statement?

Comment: Technically no. You could use an inline arrow function `numbers1.map(value => value * 2);`

Comment: Using arrow functions you can return the values without `return` - like `const myFunction = (value, index, array) => value * 2 ;`

Comment: I mean, both those examples technically use a `return` statement it just becomes implicit if you have a single-line arrow function.

Comment: If you are interested in what the function returns, use `map` and return a value. If you are not, use `forEach` or a `for` loop. Using `map` without returning a value can work, depending on what you want to do, but then it's inelegant code.

Answer (score 0):

if you use arrow functions you don't have to add return but you use regular functions like above your instaces you have to add return you don't return you will get undefined or null.